# What is difference between manage.windowsazure and portal.azure?

Tags: azure

We have bizspark and we have both of them, which one we use and what is a difference between manage.windowsazure.com and portal.azure.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manage.windowsAzure.com is the old (also called classic) portal.
while portal.azure.com is the new (most recent) portal.

The aim is that the new portal replaces the old (classic) one. But some functionnalities are not entirely migrated.
The best practice is to use the new portal in first place.

Here is announcement of the new portal with the key features and improvements  https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/announcing-azure-portal-general-availability/

Comment: You may also want to read this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902089/manage-windowsazure-com-vs-portal-azure-com

Comment: Thanks for answer, there are some functionnalities in manage.windowsazure but there are not in portal.azure.Well can I use all functionnalities  with azure CLI ?

Comment: Azure CLI uses Azure APIs which should cover all functionnalities

Comment: Can you please mark as answered to close the thread ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the https://portal.azure.com/ is the future of Azure's web-based management. As to which services / features are in which management portal during the transition between the two, that information can be [found on the Azure documentation website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/azure-portal/availability/).