# Get classic portal disks Azure REST

Tags: rest, azure, azure-authentication, azure-disk

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subID/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks?api-version=2017-03-30

this gives me all Disks of New Azure portal.

replacing the above Microsoft.Compute to Microsoft.ClassicCompute does not give me the classic portal disks as there is no resource type called disks under classiccompute namespace.

what is the alternate to get classic portal disks?

Have tried https://management.core.windows.net/subid/services/disks but this uses a different auth mechanism all together is there any other endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to get the classic disks so we can Azure service management REST API  that you mentioned.

```
https://management.core.windows.net/subscription-id/services/disks
```

How to authenticate Service Management Requests  please refer to the [official document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx#bk_cert).

> Use X509 Certificate - You can always use X509 Certificate based authorization to authorize your SM API requests

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = GetStoreCertificate(Thumbprint);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
```

How to create a new self-signed certificate please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-certs-create#create-a-new-self-signed-certificate)

We also need to upload the certificate under subscription.

[image]

The following is my test result via postman.
[image]

Other related links:

[manage.windowsazure.com vs. portal.azure.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902089/manage-windowsazure-com-vs-portal-azure-com?answertab=active#tab-top)